# Next js/react Unable to set a cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies, next.js

so i am trying to get a cookie in next js and using express but the backend works fine with postman and get the cookie token but the problem is the frontend is not getting the cookie and here is my backend:

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("token", req.body.token).send({ msg: "DONE" });
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("running on http://localhost:5000");
});
```

and here is the frontend:

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home({ cookies }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>Cookies: {cookies}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fetch(`http://localhost:5000/`, {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ token: "ACBD" }),
          });
        }}
      >
        Genrate Cookies
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it is returning:

Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Failed to fetch

is there a mistake here also i have tried to put this in a `getServerSideProps()` but it still does not work.

Comment: try this in the backend: `app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:CLIENT_PORT", credentials: true }));`  and `credentials: "include",`  to the header in client side

Comment: i have added your suggestion it does fix the TypeError: Failed to fetch error but it still does not set a cookie in nextjs but does work in postman

Answer (score -2):

I use js-cookie. it works great
get and set Cookies in React.useEffect in the frontend

Comment: no the thing is i am trying to get a cookie from the backend I have tried ```js-cookie ``` and it works fine but the problem is it does set a cookie from the backend